# Error in swi-prolog family tree

Tags: error-handling, prolog

I'm trying to learn the basics of swi-prolog and I started with a simple family tree.  When I try to compile the code it keeps giving me a `Syntax error: Operator expected` on lines 47-53 and a `Singleton variables:[B, C]` warning on lines 60 and 61.  If anyone familiar with the language could take a look at the code and tell me what I could be doing wrong it would be much appreciated.  Also, if anyone could recommend a good swi-prolog compiler it would be much appreciated.

Here's the code

```
%
%Lineage
%

parent_child(stan, lisa).
parent_child(stan, steve).
parent_child(gertrude, steve).
parent_child(steve, adam).
parent_child(steve, brian).
parent_child(steve, jessie).
parent_child(ann, jessie).
parent_child(lisa, dave).
parent_child(allice, adam).
parent_child(ann, brian).

%
%Gender
%

male(adam).
male(brian).
male(dave).
male(kyle).
male(steve).
male(stan).
female(allice).
female(ann).
female(jessie).
female(gertrude).
female(lisa).

%
%Relation Clauses
%

father(X, Y) :- parent_child(X, Y), male(X).
mother(X, Y) :- parent_child(X, Y), feamle(X).

grandfather(X, Z) :- parent_child(X, Y), parent_child(Y, Z), male(X).
grandmother(X, Z) :- parent_child(X, Y), parent_child(Y, Z), female(X).

brother(X, Y) :- parent_child(A, X), parent_child(B, X), parent_child(A, Y), 
                 parent_child(B, Y), female(A), male(B), male(Y).
brothers(X, Y) :- parent_child(A, X), parent_child(B, X), parent_child(A, Y), 
                  parent_child(B, Y), female(A), male(B), male(X), male(y).
sister(X, Y) :- parent_child(A, X), parent_child(B, X), parent_child(A, Y), 
                parent_child(B, Y), female(A), male(B), female(Y).
sisters(X, Y) :- parent_child(A, X), parent_child(B, X), parent_child(A, Y), 
                 parent_child(B, Y), female(A), male(B), female(X), female(Y).

aunt(X, Y) :- parent_child(A, X), parent_child(B, Y), Parent(A, B).
aunt_nephew(X, Y) :- parent_child(A, X), parent_child(B, Y), Parent(A, B), 
                     female(X), male(Y).
aunt_niece(X, Y) :- parent_child(A, X), parent_child(B, Y), Parent(A, B), 
                    female(X), female(Y).

uncle(X, Y) :- parent_child(A, X), parent_child(B, Y), Parent(A, B).
uncle_nephew(X, Y) :- parent_child(A, X), parent_child(B, Y), Parent(A, B), 
                      male(X), male(Y).
uncle_niece(X, Y) :- parent_child(A, X), parent_child(B, Y), Parent(A, B), 
                     male(X), female(Y).

cousin(X, Y) :- parent_child(A, X), parent_child(C, A), parent_child(B, Y), 
                parent_child(C, B).
cousin_male(X, Y) :- parent_child(A, X), parent_child(C, A), 
                     parent_child(B, Y), parent_child(C, B), male(Y).
cousin_female(X, Y) :- parent_child(A, X), parent_child(C, A), 
                       parent_child(B, Y), parent_child(C, B), female(Y).

half_brother(X, Y) :- parent_child(A, X), parent_child(A, Y), 
                      parent_child(B, X), parent_child(C, Y), male(X).
half_sister(X, Y) :- parent_child(A, X), parent_child(A, Y), 
                     parent_child(B, X), parent_child(C, Y), female(X).
```

Comment: [SWI Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) is excellent.

Comment: brothers/2 and sisters/2 are unusual. Plurality is handled in different way in Prolog (see [findall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3)/3)

Comment: @CapelliC the OP probably meant for `sister(X,Y)` to mean that `Y` is a sister of `X`, and for `sisters(X,Y)` to mean that they both are sisters to each other. So it is not about plurality, it's just a relation.

Comment: @WillNess: I see, but isn't sister/2 that relation ?

Comment: @CapelliC no, because X could be a brother to Y, in sister(X,Y) (presumably; I'm not talking about implementation, but about intent).

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the second clause of `brothers(X,Y):- ... male(B), male(X), male(y).` All variables must start with an upper case letter.

All *predicates* must start with a *lower case* letter. In the lines 47 - 53 there is a predicate call "`Parent(A, B)`", which starts with an upper case letter. That is invalid syntax. When it is changed to `parent(A, B)`, the errors go away.

The warnings about singleton variables mean that that variable is used only once in a body of a predicate, i.e. its value isn't used. You could just use a nameless var `_` instead. Usually this means that you've overlooked something.

Here, you've probably meant that `B \= C`. Same goes for other vars as well, like `X` and `Y`, probably.

Just using differently named variables does not ensure that their values are different, you need to add an explicit check for that - *after* both variables have been instantiated. To register your intent *before* they are instantiated, you must use [`dif/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=dif/2):

```
2 ?- dif(X,Y),X=1,Y=2.

X = 1
Y = 2

3 ?- dif(X,Y),X=1,Y=1.

No
```